# Setting the width of a Silverlight combo box to accommodate its widest item

Tags: silverlight, combobox

In a Silverlight application I have a number of combo boxes with data content. How do I set the width of the combo box so that it can accommodate its widest item?

I have created a hack that works in WPF, but it does not work in Silverlight – which is both unfortunately and expected ;^(

I might be able to create a workaround by measuring the width of the text but that would be a very hard coded implementation so I would like to find another way.

I cannot really believe that this is not a supported scenario, but I have not been able to find an solution. I hope there is something I have missed…

Answer (score 0):

It would be hardcoded if you databound, then cycled thru the elements measuring the text width?  Seems fairly dynamic (if clunky)

Comment: The method of measuring the widths of the texts in the elements of the combo box is hardcoded to a specific way of presenting the elements in the combo box. I would much prefer a generic solution which really *should* be not only possible but also pretty *easy* because of the measuring system of Silverlight (and WPF) - it just isn't.